# PHP: different elements between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two different arrays like this

```
 $array1 = [1, 2, 8, 10];
 $array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 1];
```

I want to get the common elements and uncommon elements between them.
I almost figured out how to get the common ones as the code below but I can't get uncommon elements.

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($array1); $x++) {

    for($z = 0; $z < count($array2); $z++) {
            if ( $array1[$x] == $array2[$z] ) {

                $array3 = $array1[$x];
                print_r($array3);

            } elseif ($array1[$x] !== $array2[$z]) {
                // code...
            }

        }
    }
```

How to get those uncommon or different elements between the two arrays without using a built-in PHP method then output them in a new array.

Comment: Watch php array functions like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: I mentioned that I need to know the answer without using any built-in functions or methods

Answer (score 1):

You can get the uncommon elements by using `in_array()` function

```
<?php
 $array1 = [1, 2, 8, 10];
 $array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 1];

  $result = []; 
 for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($array2);$i++){
 if(!in_array($array2[$i],$array1)){
    $result[] =  $array2[$i];
  }
 }
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 15
)
```

Comment: what if we cant use in_array method, how to do it?

Comment: You can do it by two for loops for both the arrays and set  the cindition as if their indexes not  intersect fill them in an empty array and later on just print that resultant array